# Get mp3 from Azure Text To Speech by Azure Function in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, azure-functions, text-to-speech

Hey fellow developers,

I'm currently working on a Unity project where I need to use Azure's Text to Speech service to generate speech audio. To accomplish this, I've set up an Azure Function that takes in a text input and returns an MP3 file of the generated audio.

I've managed to successfully call the Azure Function from Unity and get the MP3 file using Unity's UnityWebRequestMultimedia. However, when it finish, I keep receiving the following error:

`Error: Cannot create FMOD::Sound instance for clip "" (FMOD error: Unsupported file or audio format. ) UnityEngine.Networking.DownloadHandlerAudioClip:GetContent (UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest) __temp_text2speech_azure/<GetSpeechBytes>d__6:MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/__temp_text2speech_azure.cs:44) UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator,intptr)`

This is Azure Functions code:

```
        [FunctionName("HTTP_Auth_TextToSpeech")]
        public static async Task<dynamic> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string text = req.Query["text"];
            string voiceName = req.Query["voiceName"];
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            text = text ?? data?.text;
            voiceName = voiceName ?? data?.voiceName;

            var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("<tts key>", "<region>");
            speechConfig.SpeechSynthesisVoiceName = voiceName;

            SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig);
            var result = synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text).Result;
        }
```

This is Unity Scripts:

```
        string text = "hello world";
        string url = $"https://<azurefunction_url>?text={text}&&voiceName={voiceName}";

        UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(url, AudioType.MPEG);
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (request.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.Log("error here");
        }
        else
        {
            AudioClip downloadClip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(request);
            audioSource.clip = downloadClip;
            audioSource.Play();
        }
```

I am trying to modify the return value or cancel the return value of an Azure Function, but it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I created speech service in cognitive services in azure.

[image]
Here is the code which converts text format to speech audio format as per the requirement.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class TextToSpeechConverter : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string SubscriptionKey = "366b07789ee84f82ac5b258889f977ae";
    private const string Region = "eastus";
    private const string OutputFilePath = "output.wav";
    private const string TextToSynthesize = "Hello, world!";

    public static object UnityWebRequest { get; private set; }

    private async void Start()
    {
        await ConvertTextToSpeechAsync(TextToSynthesize, OutputFilePath);
        await DownloadAudioFileAsync(OutputFilePath);
    }

    private static async Task ConvertTextToSpeechAsync(string text, string outputFile)
    {
        var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(SubscriptionKey, Region);
        var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileOutput(outputFile);

        using (var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(config, audioConfig))
        {
            using (var result = await synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text))
            {
                if (result.Reason == ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted)
                {
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Speech synthesized to file.");
                }
                else if (result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
                {
                    var cancellation = SpeechSynthesisCancellationDetails.FromResult(result);
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log($"Speech synthesis canceled. Reason: {cancellation.Reason}");

                    if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                    {
                        UnityEngine.Debug.Log($"Speech synthesis error. ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}, ErrorDetails={cancellation.ErrorDetails}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task DownloadAudioFileAsync(string filePath)
    {
        using (var www = UnityWebRequest.Get($"file://{filePath}"))
        {
            await www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                // Save the downloaded audio file
                var audioData = www.downloadHandler.data;
                var audioFileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                var savePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, audioFileName);
                File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, audioData);

                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Audio file downloaded and saved: " + savePath);
            }
            else
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Failed to download audio file: " + www.error);                                                                                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works fine.

[image]

Result:
[image]